# Visual studio 2010 web application deployment

Tags: asp.net

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 sp1 on Windows 7 23bit. I have recently converted my web application from Visual Studio 2008. When I try to compile my web app, by clicking on "publish website" it tells me "Publish succeeded" but the deployment folder is empty. I even checked to see whether I have syntax errors. I have none, that I could locate. I also did some extensive googling but no satisfactory answer. What is causing this? Am I missing something here? Is it a bug from Visual Studio 2010? Your help would be very much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: 23-bit?  I didn't know there was a CLR for that...

Comment: to re-iterate @fretje: when you publish, where are you publishing to web deploy, ftp, file system,  or FPSE.  Also do you have it set to "replace matching files with local copies"?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to compile my web app, by clicking on "publish website" When you compile application it doesn't publish if you want to publish you need to go in Solution Explorer and right click mouse button, and press Publish

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to put files in the folder you are publishing to? i.e. a file permission issue.

Comment: Yes I do have full access to my publishing folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open your web application project property page.

There, under the tab **Package/Publish Web** you will see where is your app being published.